# PHPExcel get display value of unknown type

Tags: phpexcel

It is possible to use getValue(), getCalculatedValue() and getOldCalculatedValue() to retrieve the value of a cell in phpexcel.

Is there a way to determine programatically the content type of the cell and apply the corresponding correct method. I need to use this in a general way. i.e. to display the same value as when opening excel.

I know there is something called getDataType() but not sure how to apply it in this case (not in documentation). In my experience sometimes only one of these three retrieves the correct value.

(i.e. sometimes getOldCalculatedValue works but not getCalculatedValue for a formula for example. other times only getvalue works, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getOldCalculatedValue()` is used to retrieve the result of a previous calculation in MS Excel itself; and should not be relied on, because it is possible to disable autocalculate in MS Excel, which can leave this field empty, or even with an incorrect value. It is used within PHPExcel as a "fallback" for cell formulae that are reliant on external spreadsheet data, but it still shouldn't be trusted as an absolute.

`getValue()` returns the "raw" value of the cell. The returned value may require "interpretation". A cell containing a date and/or time is simply a float value in MS Excel, so it will return that float (e.g. `42017.7916666667` instead of a human-readable date/time like `13-Jan-2015 19:00`;
and it will return the actual formula if a cell contains a formula (e.g. `=TODAY()`); or `0.8` for a value that might be formatted as a percentage and that appears as `80%` in MS Excel itself.

`getCalculatedValue()` will attempt to execute a formula calculation if a cell contains a formula, and return the result of that calculation. If the cell doesn't contain a formula, then it will return the "raw" value, in the same way as `getValue()`. While PHPExcel has a fairly good calculation engine, it isn't perfect (it can't handle 3d cell ranges or array formulae for example), so it is possible for some formulae to fail. Likewise, formulae containing references to external resources may also fail, and while PHPExcel will attempt to use the `getOldCalculatedValue()` in that circumstance, it isn't (as mentioned above) guaranteed to maintain the correct result.

`getFormattedValue()` will execute `getCalculatedValue()`, and then apply any number formatting mask that applies to that cell against the result, so that (for example) a float with a date mask will be displayed as a date. 
However, if you've loaded a spreadsheet file with readDataOnly(true), then that tells PHPExcel ***not*** to load any formatting, including number format masks, so it will not be able to format the result.

When you access MS Excel itself, then the closest result to the values displayed in MS Excel itself will be `getFormattedValue()`

Comment: is there a way to check if formulae contains references to external resources?